# Is objective C mandatory for creating an iphone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Is it mandatory for a developer to be well versed with Objective-C if planning to develop a simple app for iphone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of non Objective-C solutions, but they're clunky as heck and users can sense pretty quickly that these apps aren't necessarily optimized for iOS.

Still, people use them.

E.G. [Xamarin (e.g. MonoTouch)](http://xamarin.com/monotouch), [Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/), [Sencha](http://www.sencha.com/), good ol' [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/), etc.

Comment: Don't Forget RubyMotion! Anyway if you want to make an App, learn Objective C.

Answer (score 1):

It's not mandatory because App Store Review Guidelines doesn't say you have to use iOS SDK to make App Store apps.

Meanwhile, there's also an application called **AppStudio** that lets you develop **iOS** and **Android** apps.  Just as Mr. Dautemann says, I wouldn't use it.  Developing iOS apps with it is like developing **Mac** applications with **REAL Studio**, which is bug-infested and is never ready for the Cocoa-build.

Answer (score 1):

There are many solutions if you don't want to learn Objective-c. You can use any cross platform like PhoneGap, Sencha as [Michael Dautermann](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16492311/767730) said.

But I will tell you little difference. If you want to develop iOS application **Sencha Touch Framework** is Excellent Framework. It provides structruing of the web app and many more.But you need to learn their language too.

If you go for **PhoneGap** you just require HTML,CSS and Javascript. Its very easy, but disadvantage of the phonegap is that your app will not be be as smooth native application. It's kind of Hybrid Web Application.

Moral: This tools are useful if you want to develop application for all the platform but if you want to develop application for iOS only, then go for Objective-c. Its much better.

Answer (score 1):

I think Titanium Appcelerator is the best option to program in ios development, you can coding in titanium just like JavaScript. And this code will be compile to objective c code, means you are just using native control of cocoa framework. And of the benefit is you can simply port this code to Android also.